# Unable to download CiviCRM

Tags: error, installation

Unable to download from site http://www.civicrmfr.org/

"The requested URL /civicrm-{{stable}}-joomla.tar.gz was not found on this server."

But OK on Sourceforge.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you download CiviCRM from the official download page:

https://civicrm.org/download